# Is it possible to access Swift global variables from an objective-c file?

Tags: objective-c, swift, global

I am working on a project where I must extend an objective-c application with some Swift code. So I need to access the Swift code from an .m file.

I imported the generated Swift.h file and now I have access to the methods, but not to the global variables.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID53) on Swift and Objective-C type compatibility the answer is no:

> When you create a Swift class that descends from an Objective-C class, the class and its members—properties, methods, subscripts, and initializers—that are compatible with Objective-C are automatically available from Objective-C. This excludes Swift-only features, such as those listed here:
>
> - Generics
> - Tuples
> - Enumerations defined in Swift without `Int` raw value type
> - Structures defined in Swift
> - Top-level functions defined in Swift
> - ***Global variables defined in Swift***
> - Typealiases defined in Swift
> - Swift-style variadics
> - Nested types
> - Curried functions

Comment: __Update:__ it's possible to bridge enums defined in swift, by adding the `@objc` flag, and deriving from an `Int`.

Comment: This list is super useful and seemingly no longer available on any official Apple site...