# How would you incorporate a Swift struct/enum into Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, struct, enums

Scenario: I've exposed the Objective-C file to Swift via the .h bridge; so I can launch the Objective-C via Storyboard from .Swift.

However, 
I have some global enum & structs declared in Environment.Swift file that ObjC needs:

```
enum BarButtonItem:Int {
    case cancel = 1
    case back
    case save
    case activate
    case upload
    case share
}
```

Accessing enum within Swift:

```
  @IBAction func navButtonAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if let buttonItem = BarButtonItem(rawValue: sender.tag) {
            switch buttonItem {
            case .save:
                println("{(3.3)AccessBoundaries} Save.")
            default:
                println("")
            }
        }
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I want to access this (and other data types) in an Objective-C file:

```
- (IBAction)barButtonAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    BarButtonItem....?
}
```

Xcode doesn't recognize this.

How do I expose environment data types (or can I?) defined in a .Swift file to an Objective-C file? 
...and, is it possible to interpret a .Swift's struct in Objective-C?
[image]

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of Swift features that can't be used in Objective-C. I posted an [answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26960714/887210) the other day that asked something similar. I'll re-post the answer here:

According to [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_86) on Swift and Objective-C compatibility:

> You’ll have access to anything within a class or protocol that’s
>   marked with the @objc attribute as long as it’s compatible with
>   Objective-C. This ***excludes*** Swift-only features such as those listed
>   here:
>
> - Generics
> - Tuples
> - **Enumerations defined in Swift**
> - **Structures defined in Swift**
> - Top-level functions defined in Swift
> - **Global variables defined in Swift**
> - Typealiases defined in Swift
> - Swift-style variadics
> - Nested types
> - Curried functions